# Is there any place to legitimately download Office 2007 Home and School?

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm 'fixing' a hosed Vista box as a favor (3 years of not running any virus software has played a toll on it) by installing Windows 7 on it. Doing a full wipe.

They have a license for MS Office 2007 Home and Student. I have the box with the key, but they have no idea where the disks are for it anymore.

Via Ninite, I installed the MS Office 2007 trial version, but the key won't work with it...I think it's because the trial version I have is for standard rather than Home/Student. I also have the license key for their copy of Publisher 2007, but again, no disks.

I've been hunting all over the MS site and it seems they only offer downloads of 2010.

Anyone know if MS has the 2007 Home and Student version hidden somewhere for download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the direct download links for all versions of Microsoft Office 2007 on [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/direct-download-links-for-microsoft-office-2007-suites-and-applications/).

The files are hosted Digital River which is a company Microsoft uses for distributing their software.

**Edit:** As of Feb 2015 this link no longer leads to an available download.